# How to restore windows 7 font tahoma8.reg

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

I have replaced the basic theme for windows 7
http://cryer.deviantart.com/art/Windows-7-Basic-Black-166606584
but after I use this registry I do not like it , I am very confused ..
I want my fonts back to normal , but always to no avail ..
please help me, thank you ..
I use this registry ,

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"FontSmoothingType"=dword:00000001
"FontSmoothing"="0"
"FontSmoothingGamma"=dword:00000000
"FontSmoothingOrientation"=dword:00000001


[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"FontSmoothing"="1"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics]
"BorderWidth"="-15"
"CaptionFont"=hex:f5,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,90,01,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,54,00,61,00,68,00,6f,00,6d,00,61,00,00,00,49,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"CaptionHeight"="-315"
"CaptionWidth"="-315"
"IconFont"=hex:f5,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,90,01,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,54,00,61,00,68,00,6f,00,6d,00,61,00,00,00,49,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"IconTitleWrap"="1"
"MenuFont"=hex:f5,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,90,01,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,54,00,61,00,68,00,6f,00,6d,00,61,00,00,00,49,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"MenuHeight"="-270"
"MenuWidth"="-270"
"MessageFont"=hex:f5,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,90,01,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,54,00,61,00,68,00,6f,00,6d,00,61,00,00,00,49,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"ScrollHeight"="-255"
"ScrollWidth"="-255"
"SmCaptionFont"=hex:f5,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,90,01,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,54,00,61,00,68,00,6f,00,6d,00,61,00,00,00,49,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"SmCaptionHeight"="-225"
"SmCaptionWidth"="-225"
"StatusFont"=hex:f5,ff,ff,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,90,01,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,54,00,61,00,68,00,6f,00,6d,00,61,00,00,00,49,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"Shell Icon Size"="32"
"AppliedDPI"=dword:00000060
"PaddedBorderWidth"="0"
"IconSpacing"="-1125"
"IconVerticalSpacing"="-1125"
"MinAnimate"="0"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts]
"Segoe UI (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Bold (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Italic (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Bold Italic (TrueType)"=""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes]
"Segoe UI"="Tahoma"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Avalon.Graphics\DISPLAY1]
"ClearTypeLevel"=dword:00000000
"EnhancedContrastLevel"=dword:00000000
"TextContrastLevel"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Avalon.Graphics\DISPLAY1]
"PixelStructure"=dword:00000000
"GammaLevel"=dword:0000076c

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main]

"UseClearType"="no"
```

Comment: Did you backup your registry before you applied the changes, if you did not, then you are out of luck.

Comment: I guess they missed this part on the deviantart page they linked to "BACKUP YOUR SYSTEM/REGISTRY FIRST"

Answer (score -1):

Don't think you have this problem, but I thought I'd post the solution for others.

"

Return font smoothing in Windows 8.1, if it was disabled by this manual
http://forum.ru-board.com/topic.cgi?forum=62&topic=18650

1) Remove Segoe UI from the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SOFTWARE \ Microsoft \ Windows NT \ CurrentVersion \ FontSubstitutes
2) Return to the HKEY_CURRENT_USER \ Control Panel \ Desktop
options:
FontSmoothing = 2
FontSmoothingType = 2
3) Apply Reg-file SegoeUI.reg, here are the contents

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SOFTWARE \ Microsoft \ Windows NT \ CurrentVersion \ Fonts]
"Segoe UI Symbol (TrueType)" = "seguisym.ttf"
"Segoe UI Italic (TrueType)" = "segoeuii.ttf"
"Segoe UI Semilight (TrueType)" = "segoeuisl.ttf"
"Segoe UI Black Italic (TrueType)" = "seguibli.ttf"
"Segoe UI Light Italic (TrueType)" = "seguili.ttf"
"Segoe UI Emoji (TrueType)" = "seguiemj.ttf"
"Segoe UI (TrueType)" = "segoeui.ttf"
"Segoe UI Semibold (TrueType)" = "seguisb.ttf"
"Segoe UI Light (TrueType)" = "segoeuil.ttf"
"Segoe UI Semilight Italic (TrueType)" = "seguisli.ttf"
"Segoe UI Black (TrueType)" = "seguibl.ttf"
"Segoe UI Bold Italic (TrueType)" = "segoeuiz.ttf"
"Segoe UI Semibold Italic (TrueType)" = "seguisbi.ttf"
"Segoe UI Bold (TrueType)" = "segoeuib.ttf"

"